# Creating an extension for TFS - how to target dashboard

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We make extensive use of dashboards for helping the business track status of projects.

One problem is the widgets for dashboards are really quite limited in terms of what they can do.

I've already written the code I need for use in an Excel extension, e.g. to grab a team's capacity and compare with work remaining, however I want to bundle this in a widget.

I've been through tutorial for creating an extension and managed to deploy a basic one.

However, I cannot see how to make sure my widget only becomes available as a dashboard extension - the default seems to be as a tab on an existing page.

How can I set it so it shows only in the list of extensions that appear on the create / edit dashboard page?

After I've installed it, which puts it on a tab I don't want, if I then go look for it on a dashboard, it doesn't appear, so I go to the other link, where I find a page asking me to Install it again... doesn't make sense.

It feels like it ought to be possible via the Extension Points but again none of these indicate how you'd simply make it accessible on dashboard without requiring a fixed location.

Answer (score 3):

There are dozens of places where you can add to the VSTS user interface. You could get started from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/overview?view=vsts).

To add a dashboard widget, you need to refer to the article below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-dashboard-widget?view=vsts

> - The **type** of contribution. For all widgets, this should be `ms.vss-dashboards-web.widget`.
> - The array of **targets** to which the contribution is contributing. For    all widgets, this should be
>     `[ms.vss-dashboards-web.widget-catalog]`.

Comment: I found that sample and while I can get it to build OK I keep getting 'widget failed to load' whenever I install it and view it on the dashboard.

Comment: That means your extension still has problem need to be fixed. You can download the complete samples here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/widgets and follow Step 6 and Step 7 directly to publish the sample extension to see whether it works or not.

Comment: Thank you - I did persevere and I got it working, however am finding it nigh on impossible to find further examples that reference other abilities, e.g. getTeams.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT is there any newer doco than this, i.e. after the last major update last year? Are there any articles or examples of writing a dashboard widget using angular and typescript?